# Validate if either or both of two fields has been provided, as a ValidationAttribute

Tags: c#, .net, validation

I have a binding model where at least one of two fields must be specified. I can't just set them both as `[Required]`. Here is what I came up with:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace MyApp.Utils.DataAnnotations
{
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = true)]
    public class EitherRequiredAttribute : ValidationAttribute
    {
        private readonly string _field1;
        private readonly string _field2;

        public EitherRequiredAttribute(string field1, string field2) => (_field1, _field2) = (field1, field2);

        protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            var property1 = validationContext.ObjectType.GetProperty(_field1);
            if (property1 == null)
                return new ValidationResult(string.Format("Unknown property: {0}", _field1), new[] { _field1 });
            var property2 = validationContext.ObjectType.GetProperty(_field2);
            if (property2 == null)
                return new ValidationResult(string.Format("Unknown property: {0}", _field2), new[] { _field2 });

            var value1 = property1.GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance);

            if (value1 != null)
                return ValidationResult.Success;

            var value2 = property2.GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance);

            if (value2 != null)
                return ValidationResult.Success;

            return new ValidationResult(string.Format("Either or both of \"{0}\" and \"{1}\" are required", _field1, _field2), new[] { _field1, _field2 });
        }
    }
}
```

Use case:

```
[EitherRequired("A", "B")]
public class SomeModel
{
    public int? A {get; set;}
    public int? B {get; set;}
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Fields and properties are different things. You are mixing them up: the naming in the attribute code suggests that you want to operate on fields, but the use site is supplying property names. The naming of `field1` and `field2` should be changed to `propertyName1` and `propertyName2` respectively.

Don't forget your [`BindingFlags`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.bindingflags?view=netframework-4.8)! Right now your code will look up any public property with the given name, *including static properties*. You probably only want public *instance* properties:

```
var property1 = validationContext.ObjectType.GetProperty(_field1, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);
```

Depending on your performance constraints, reflection might be too slow for you. If so, it's common practice to cache the results of calls to `GetProperty` since that information is unchanging at runtime.

It's good practice to use `nameof` for getting string representations of identifiers, because if `SomeModel.A` gets renamed then the program won't compile until you also update the attribute argument.

```
[EitherRequired(nameof(A), nameof(B))]
public class SomeModel
{
    public int? A {get; set;}
    public int? B {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: I stumbled over the naming as well without mentioning it. Good call, but `propertyName1` would be better than `property1`. Nevertheless +1

Comment: Agreed on `propertyName1`. Updated.

Answer (score 3):

Your code looks almost neat and clean, but there are still some areas where you could improve it.

- Althought braces may be optional for single line `if` statements your code will get less error-prone by using them.
- Some more vertical spacing (new lines) would improve the readability of the code.
- The class `EitherRequiredAttribute` could be named better. I would suggest to name it `AtLeastOneRequiredAttribute`. Using this name makes the purpose of the class and the annotation more clear.
- You only check if `valueX == null` hence you could omit both `value1` and `value2` and just check if the call to `GetValue()` returns `null`.
- Instead of having

  ```
  var property1 = validationContext.ObjectType.GetProperty(_field1);
  if (property1 == null)
      return new ValidationResult(string.Format("Unknown property: {0}", _field1), new[] { _field1 });  
  var property2 = validationContext.ObjectType.GetProperty(_field2);
  if (property2 == null)
      return new ValidationResult(string.Format("Unknown property: {0}", _field2), new[] { _field2 });
  ```

  you could introduce a method `bool TryGetProperty(string, ValidationContext, out PropertyInfo)`.

Implementing the mentioned points would lead to

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = true)]
public class AtLeastOneRequiredAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    private readonly string _field1;
    private readonly string _field2;

    public EitherRequiredAttribute(string field1, string field2) => (_field1, _field2) = (field1, field2);

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (!TryGetProperty(_field1, validationContext, out var property1))
        {
            return new ValidationResult(string.Format("Unknown property: {0}", _field1), new[] { _field1 });
        }

        if (!TryGetProperty(_field2, validationContext, out var property2))
        {
            return new ValidationResult(string.Format("Unknown property: {0}", _field2), new[] { _field1 });
        }

        if (property1.GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance) != null ||
            property2.GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance) != null)
        {
            return ValidationResult.Success;
        }

        return new ValidationResult(string.Format("Either or both of \"{0}\" and \"{1}\" are required", _field1, _field2), new[] { _field1, _field2 });
    }
    private bool TryGetProperty(string fieldName, ValidationContext validateionContext, out PropertyInfo propertyInfo)
    {
        return (propertyInfo = validateionContext.ObjectType.GetProperty(fieldName)) != null;
    }
}
```

Althought methods named `TryGetXXX` are indicating that no exception should be thrown by calling them, this method will throw if `fieldName` is either `null` or `WhitheSpace`.

Comment: Regarding your last comment, you probably should validate that in the constructor.